# formula for the sum of n+n/2+n/3+...+n/n

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, calculus

so I got this algorithm I need to calculate its time complexity

which goes like

```
for i=1 to n do
    k=i
    while (k<=n) do
        FLIP(A[k])
        k = k + i
```

where `A` is an array of booleans, and FLIP is as it is, flipping the current value. therefore it's `O(1)`.

Now I understand that the inner while loop should be called

```
n/1+n/2+n/3+...+n/n
```

If I'm correct, but is there a formula out there for such calculation?

pretty confused here

Comment: FLIP is O(1), I couldn't find the edit button for some reason :X, and I got the expression in the title by trying with a sample array of size 10, in the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will iterate 10 times, in the second one the inner loop will iterate 5 times and the third time will iterate 3 times and so on..

Comment: The edit button is right under your question. If you cannot find it, use your browser "search on page" function. For more info see [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: @RoryDaulton, note the `k = k + i` in the pseudo code (not `k = k + 1`).

Answer (score 6):

The more exact computation is `T(n) \sum((n-i)/i)` for `i = 1 to n` (because `k` is started from `i`). Hence, the final sum is `n + n/2 + ... + n/n - n = n(1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n) - n`, approximately. We knew `1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n = H(n)` and `H(n) = \Theta(\log(n)). Hence, T(n) = \Theta(n\log(n))`. The `-n` has not any effect on the asymptotic computaional cost, as `n = o(n\log(n))`.

Comment: I can't understand how the -n has anything to do with this formula?
I understand how it got from this (n/1)+(n/2)+...+(n/n) to H(n) which is equal to ln(n) but also I need to multiply everything by n, so it comes to n*ln(n) isn't it?

Comment: @stylo as I've mentioned because `n = o(n\log(n))` (`o` means `little-oh`).

Answer (score 4):

Lets say we want to calculate sum of this equation

```
  n + n / 2 + n / 3 + ... + n / n
=> n ( 1 + 1 / 2 + 1 / 3 + ..... + 1 / n )
```

Then in bracket **( 1 + 1 / 2 + 1 / 3 + ... + 1 / n )** this is a well known [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) and i am afraid there is no proven formula to calculate Harmonic series.

Comment: There is a formula that expresses the asymptotic behaviour of the harmonic series, which is what OP mist likely needs.

Answer (score 0):

The given problem boils down to calculate below sum -[Sum of harmonic series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjPbv.gif)

Although this sum can't be calculated accurately, however you can still find asymptotic upper bound for this sum, which is approximately O(**log(n)**).

Hence answer to above problem will be - O(**nlog(n)**)